# Reading from Excel and storing content in database - works as procedure, but when executed from C# console app, it breaks

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, oledb

So the title is pretty self-explanatory.

I have a stored procedure that executes and does the job. Here's the relevant part:

```
SELECT O.* FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'
        , 'Excel 12.0; Database=D:\File.xlsx; HDR=YES'
        , 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'
        ) AS O
```

So the "database" location is not in the same folder as console app. Don't know if that's in issue - I believe it shouldn't be. So, when executing the procedure from the code:

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("CreateAndSeedTable", connection) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
```

Throws this error (note: all other procedures work well):

> Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".
>
> OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Unspecified error".

Why would calling procedure from code make throw an error? And what's the workaround?

Comment: Without seeing most of your code, it's hard to say why your db connection errors iut saying you are connecting to null server. Check conn strings

Comment: It works with other stored procedures that do not read from excel, so the con is fine.

Comment: how are you attempting to read from excel file

Answer (score 0):

OPENROWSET is an sql function, that runs on the sql database server. The ACE driver, and the spreadsheet path, must be readable by the server process.

Is that really what you intend to do? Or do you want your c# console program to read the spreadsheet contents, process them and send them to the sql server?

Comment: Yes, i want to call SQL procedure. If it works directly on the sql server, why wouldn't it if I call the same procedure from console app?

Comment: Just pointing out that there's a subtle difference here between developing on your machine, with all the services running in the same place, as the same user. And deploying that solution to multiple different machines, with each part running as a separate user.

Comment: I'm running everything in developer environment, same machine

Answer (score 0):

There might be an error due to Excel Version.. Try This..

```
                if (filename.EndsWith(".xls"))
                {
                    connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;", pathToExcelFile);
                }
                else if (filename.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
                {
                    connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + pathToExcelFile + "';Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\"";
                }
```

Comment: No, it works directly as the stored procedure so the driver is okay I guess